# Finding the general solution of the differential equation $\,\,y''+y=f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck with the following problem:

> I have to show that the general solution of the differential equation $$y''+y=f(x)\,\, ,x \in (-\infty,\infty)$$, where $f$ is continuous real valued function on  $(-\infty,\infty)$ is $$y(x)=A \cos x+B \sin x + \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \sin (x-t) dt\,\, $$ where $A,B$ are constants.

C.F. part of the reduced differential equation $y''+y=0$ is : $A \cos x+B \sin x$. But I am having trouble to get the P.I.(particular integral) which can be obtained by solving $$\frac {1}{D^2+1} f(x)$$,where $D \equiv \frac {d}{dx}$. This is where I am stuck.

Am I going in the right direction? Can someone help?

Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: Have you learned about Green's functions? Or have you considered trying laplace transforms? Either of those methods should work.

Comment: You have to show or you have to find?

Comment: I have to show ...

Comment: If you define $h(x)$ as the added integral, then differentiating twice (using extra rule for differentiation under the integral sign) shows that $h(x)+h''(x)=f(x).$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recalling the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of a function $f$

> $$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,e^{-sx}dx $$

Taking the Laplace transform of the ode

$$ y''+y=f(x) $$

yields

$$ s^2Y(s)+Y(s)-s \,y(0)-y'(0)=F(s) $$

$$ \implies Y(s)=\frac{y'(0)}{s^2+1}+\frac{y(0)s}{s^2+1}+\frac{F(s)}{s^2+1} $$

Now, we take the inverse Laplace transform of the above equation to get

$$ y(x) = A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)+ \int_{0}^{x} \sin(x-t)f(t)dt. $$

**Notes:**

1) $$ \mathcal{L}\,y^{(n)}(x) = s^n F(s) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} s^{k-1} f^{(n-k)}(0). $$

2) $$\mathcal{L} (\sin(x))=\frac{1}{s^2+1},\quad \mathcal{L} (\cos(x))=\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$

3) $$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s)G(s))=(f*g)(x).  $$

Comment: Who guarantees that $y, y''$ and $f$ admit a Laplace transform?

Comment: @AlexM. What do you even mean?

Comment: @Angel: Remember that the Laplace transform of $f$ is $\int _0 ^\infty \mathrm e ^{-tx} f(x) \, \mathrm d x$. This integral does not necessarily exist for any continuous $f$ (for instance, if $f = \mathrm e ^x$ and $t \le 1$). Since the problem does not impose further conditions upon $f$, one deduces that its Laplace transform may not exist, therefore attacking the problem with the tools of this transform is not correct. Other approaches must be thought of.

Comment: @AlexM. I see your point.

Comment: @Angel: The same is true for $y$ and $y'$: how do we know that their Laplace transforms are finite? Either the OP forgot to include further simplifying hypotheses, or an alternative approach must be looked for. (Or, of course, the problem was sloppily formulated by whoever conceived it.)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the solutions to the corresponding homogenous equation are sin x and cos x . Using variation of parameters will give you the required result. Wronskian of $\cos x $ and $\sin x$ is therefore
$$
\begin{align}
y_p&= \cos x\int_{0}^x f(t) (-\sin t) dt+\sin x\int_{0}^x f(t)\cos t dt  \\
y_p&= \int_{0}^x f(t)[\sin x\cos t-\cos x\sin t]dt \\
y_p&=\int_{0}^x f(t)\sin (x-t) dt\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Just started learning to code maths. Sorry

Comment: You don't need to put as many dollar signs ....Put a single dollar then follow with math expression then put a final dollar sign

Comment: Thanks for telling me that.

Comment: You're welcome ........

Comment: why limits from 0 to x as there is no such thing in method of variation of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $y''(x)+y(x)=y''(x)-[i-(-i)]y'(x)+[i\cdot(-i)]y(x)=y''(x)-iy'(x)+i[y'(x)-iy(x)]=(y'-iy)'(x)+i(y'-iy)(x).$ Let $z=y'-iy,$ hence $z'+iz=f.$ This is equivalent to $\exp(ix)z'(x)+i\exp(ix)z(x)=\exp(ix)f(x)=[\exp^i\cdot{z}]'(x).$ Integrating on $[0,t]$ results in $$\exp(it)z(t)-z(0)=\int_0^t\exp(ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ implying $$z(t)=z(0)\exp(-it)+\exp(-it)\int_0^t\exp(ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=y(t)'-iy(t).$$ This is equivalent to $$\exp(-it)y'(t)-i\exp(-it)y(t)=[\exp^{-i}\cdot{y}]'(t)$$ $$=[y'(0)-iy(0)]\exp(-2it)+\exp(-2it)\int_0^t\exp(ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Integrating on $[0,s]$ results in $$\exp(-is)y(s)-y(0)$$ $$=\frac{i}2[y'(0)-iy(0)][\exp(-2is)-1]+\int_0^s\exp(-2it)\int_0^t\exp(ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t$$ $$=\frac{i}2[y'(0)-iy(0)][\exp(-2is)-1]+\frac{i}2\exp(-2is)\int_0^s\exp(ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{i}2\int_0^s\exp(-ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ which is equivalent to $$y(s)-y(0)\exp(is)=\frac{i}2[y'(0)-iy(0)][\exp(-is)-\exp(is)]+\frac{i}2\exp(-is)\int_0^s\exp(ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{i}2\exp(is)\int_0^s\exp(-ix)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ $$=[y'(0)-iy(0)]\sin(s)+\frac1{2i}\int_0^s(\exp[i(s-x)]-\exp[-i(s-x)]f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ $$=y'(0)\sin(s)-iy(0)\sin(s)+\int_0^s\sin(s-x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=y(s)-y(0)\cos(s)-iy(0)\sin(s).$$ Therefore, $$y(s)=y(0)\cos(s)+y'(0)\sin(s)+\int_0^s\sin(s-x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$