# Find general solution of the ODE:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find general solution of the ODE:

$\dfrac{\operatorname{d^2y}}{\operatorname{dx^2}}+y=f(x)$ where $f(x) $ is  a real valued continuous function on $(-\infty,\infty)$

C.F:
$D\equiv \dfrac{\operatorname{d^2}}{\operatorname{dx^2}}$ then $D^2+1=0$.

Hence $y=A\cos x+ B\sin x$.

I can't find the particular integral .

Comment: use the variation of parameters

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this has been asked before:

[Finding the general solution of the differential equation $\,\,y''+y=f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472927/finding-the-general-solution-of-the-differential-equation-yy-fx?rq=1)

According to this post, you are missing a $\ldots+\int_{0}^{x} \sin(x-t)f(t) \ dt$ at the end.