$u''+u\geq 0$ then $\int_{0}^{2\pi} (u'(x))^2 dx \leq \int_{0}^{2\pi} (u(x))^2 dx.$
Let $u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $2\pi$-periodic and smooth function so that $u''(x) + u(x) \geq 0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
I want to prove that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (u'(x))^2 dx \leq \int_{0}^{2\pi} (u(x))^2 dx.$$
This is like a reversed Wirtinger's inequality. Thus I tried to use Fourier series but it seemed that the condition $u''(x) + u(x) \geq 0$ is not easy to implement via this approach.

Step 1. (Reduction) We first show:

Lemma 1. In OP's problem, it suffices to consider the case $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$.

Indeed, consider $\tilde{u}(x) = u(x) - A \cos x - B \sin x$ for any constants $A$ and $B$. Then $\tilde{u}$ is also a $2\pi$-periodic smooth function so that
$$ \tilde{u}''(x) + \tilde{u}(x) = u''(x) + u(x) \geq 0. \tag{1} $$
Moreover, integrating by parts twice together with $2\pi$-periodicity shows that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} u''(x)(A\cos x + B \sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= - \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(x)(A\cos x + B \sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Hence, by integration by parts again,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (u(x)^2 - u'(x)^2) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(x)(u(x) + u''(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \tilde{u}(x)( \tilde{u}(x) +  \tilde{u}''(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
This shows that we may replace $u$ by $\tilde{u}$ if necessary. Since
$$ \tilde{u}(0) = u(0) - A
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\tilde{u}'(0) = u'(0) - B,$$
this amounts to adjusting the values of $u(0)$ and $u'(0)$ without affecting the assumption of OP's problem. Therefore the lemma follows by letting $A = u(0)$ and $B = u'(0)$ (and then replacing $u$ by the resulting $\tilde{u}$).

Step 2. (Integral Representation) In light of Lemma 1, we assume $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$ without losing generality. Also, define $f(x)$ by
$$ f(x) = u(x) + u''(x). $$
Then we have the following representation of $u$ in terms of $f$ (see this posting for the motivation).

Lemma 2. $\displaystyle u(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\sin(x - t) \, \mathrm{d}t$.

Indeed, let $v(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\sin(x - t) \, \mathrm{d}t$. Then we note that
\begin{align*}
v'(x) &= \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\cos(x - t) \, \mathrm{d}t, \\
v''(x) &= f(x) - \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\sin(x - t) \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}
From this, we have $v(0) = v'(0) = 0$ and $v + v'' = f$. Then by the uniqueness of solutions for linear ODE, we have $v = u$.

Step 3. (Useful Lower Bound). Now we prove

Lemma 3. $u(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $u$ is $2\pi$-periodic, it suffices to prove the inequality on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Let $x \in [0, \pi]$. Then using $\text{(1)}$ and Lemma 2, we get
\begin{align*}
u(x)
&= \int_{0}^{x} \underbrace{f(t)\sin(x - t)}_{\geq 0} \, \mathrm{d}t \geq 0
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
u(-x)
&= \int_{0}^{-x} f(t)\sin(-x - t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \underbrace{f(-t)\sin(x - t)}_{\geq 0} \, \mathrm{d}t
\geq 0, \tag{$t \mapsto -t$}
\end{align*}
concluding the assertion of the lemma.

Conclusion. By $\text{(1)}$, $\text{(2)}$ and Lemma 3, we get
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (u(x)^2 - u'(x)^2) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \underbrace{ u(x)(u(x) + u''(x)) }_{\geq 0} \, \mathrm{d}x
\geq 0,
\end{align*}
completing the proof.

For $u''+u=0 \to u=a\sin x +b \cos x$ so when we have $2\pi $-periodic  function for $u''+u\ge 0  \ \forall x$ It can be like $$u=a\sin x +b \cos x +c$$ to be periodic ,and for $u''+u\ge 0 $ ,$c \ge \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$
I hope this helps you start for inequallity

How to show that u must be in the form $a \sin x + b\cos x +c$?

For $u''(x)+u(x)=f(x) (\geq0)$, the general solution can be seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472927/finding-the-general-solution-of-the-differential-equation-yy-fx . Although I can't seem to work out the rest of the solution using this.

@Shean, Nice reference! I was able to make use of the observation in that link to solve OP's problem, thank you :)
